# Crossplatform File::write_at()?

Tags: file, rust, seek

I'm trying to write to a file but starting from a certain position. I've tried to use [`write_at()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/fs/trait.FileExt.html#tymethod.write_at) but it doesn't work.

1. The file is overwritten anyway, so what's the point?
2. It's a UNIX-only API, and I would like to let people use my program on for example Windows and macOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cross-platform solution is a two-step process: [seek](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html#impl-Seek-for-File), then [write](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html#impl-Write-for-File). Note that this moves the file cursor, unlike `write_at`.

```rust
let mut file = OpenOptions::new().write(true).open("example.txt")?;
file.seek(SeekFrom::Start(1234))?;
file.write_all(b"foobar")?;
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c815f995abf372a48c0a18df4795982c)